# Find all occurrences of substrings matching a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to use C# to extract from a single string all occurrences of sub-strings with pattern which is: white space followed by any text.

So for example if I have a string `“This is a very short sentence”` then I want to be able to obtain 5 strings:

```
“is a very short sentence”
“a very short sentence”
“very short sentence”
“short sentence”
“sentence”
```

From the example above sub-strings should not include leading white space. Also being able to access each obtained string by index would be great.

I tried to use regex but I was unable to bypass first match.

Please help

Comment: Why do you want to use regex, why not use split and write a loop to generate the permutations?

Comment: Have you tried Split?

Comment: Simple pseudocode : 1. Find next white space starting at S as W 2. Take substring starting at W till end of the string. 3. S = W + 1 4. Go to step 1 till you cannot find next white space. I will leave the implementation as your homework.

Comment: Should the code consider multiple spaces as single whitespace or different whitespace separators like tab? If yes, should they be kept or replaced by space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Split` and some `Linq`:

```
string text2 = "This is a very short sentence";

// Get all words except first one
var parts = text2.Split(' ').Skip(1);

// Generate various combinations 
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, parts.Count())
    .Select(i => string.Join(" ", parts.Skip(i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a try with looping and Substring method:

```
string inputStr = "This is a very short sentence";
List<string> subStringList = new List<string>();

while(inputStr.IndexOf(' ')!=-1)
{
    inputStr= inputStr.Substring(inputStr.IndexOf(' ')+1);
    subStringList.Add(inputStr);
}


Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n",subStringList));
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yWmnfA)

Comment: @degant solution better

Comment: @anete.anetes: of course, But is that a reason for a down-vote?

Comment: Yes. Because if i saw this at production i would force you to rewrite it in @degant style.

Comment: @anete.anetes I disagree. The LINQ version is more confusing than this one. Also, there might be different "whitespace" separators, which will be hard to "bring back" with LINQ, while this solution has that built-in.

Comment: @Euphoric it's about complexity Management: http://www.stevemcconnell.com/ieeesoftware/bp06.htm
in `this` solution, i need to understand something like 7-8 tokens, but in LINQ 3-4 tokens

Comment: But I would refactor this solution to have only one `IndexOf`. And I'm not sure if I like replacing the `inputStr` with it's substring instead of having `IndexOf` start at place of previous whitespace.

Comment: @anete.anetes I'm sure that is not how complexity works. In this case, it is simple loop. While in LINQ case, you have two steps, first splits and seconds rebuilds in non-intuitive way.

Comment: @Euphoric it's `while` loop, which works untill `indexOf`, inside it's `substring` of `indexOf` with `+1 magic`, after that `add to list`, and in the end `string.join`. LINQ: `split`, `range`, `select`,`join`